# Arima grid search function

Tags: python, grid, time-series, arima

I am writing a function that does a grid search for arima model based on bic criteria

I am able to do ARIMA grid search but I am trying to update it to SARIMA grid search

Code look like below I just cant make it work

```
import itertools

p_min = 0
d_min = 0
q_min = 0
p_max = 4
d_max = 0
q_max = 4

# Initialize a DataFrame to store the results
results_bic = pd.DataFrame(index=['AR{}'.format(i) for i in range(p_min,p_max+1)],
                           columns=['MA{}'.format(i) for i in range(q_min,q_max+1)])

for p,d,q in itertools.product(range(p_min,p_max+1),
                               range(d_min,d_max+1),
                               range(q_min,q_max+1)):
    if p==0 and d==0 and q==0:
        results_bic.loc['AR{}'.format(p), 'MA{}'.format(q)] = np.nan
        continue

    try:
        model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(data, order=(p, d, q),trend = "c", seasonal_order = (p, d, q,12)

                              )
        results = model.fit()
        results_bic.loc['AR{}'.format(p), 'MA{}'.format(q)] = results.bic

    except:
        continue
results_bic = results_bic[results_bic.columns].astype(float)
```

Comment: Is data defined?

Comment: yes, it is defined - I just wrote "data" to the forum so it is easies to understand

Comment: Can you add a small set of data to this question, so we cam replicate your issue?